# Need Javascript or jquery code to pass data to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Everytime `<a>` tag is pressed i need to submit form. I need to keep track the number of times `<a>` tag is pressed. It starts with 3 and every time its is submitted we increment by 6. I need to pass this number to GetArticleData Controller using Action Method.

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
  AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
  {
    UpdateTargetId = "tableBody",
    Url = Url.Action("GetArticleData")
  };  
}                 

<div class="headlines-show-more">
  @using(Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOpts))
  { 
    <a class="button-add-content"  href="#">Show More News</a>
  }
</div>

<div id="tableBody">
  @Html.Action("GetArticleData");
</div>
```

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult GetArticleData()
{
  HomePageModel model = new HomePageModel();
  model.GetDetails();
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

Partial View

```
@model Models.HomePageModel

@foreach(var item in Model.HeadlinesNews.Skip(0).Reverse().Take(9))
{                                                                     
  <a  href="@Url.Action("Index", "Article", new { id =   item.PKNewsId, title = item.NewsTitle.Replace(' ', '-') })">
    <span>
      <span>@item.Category</span>
      <span></span>
      <img src="@Url.Content("~/Uploads/Images/" + item.Image)">
      <span>
        <span></span>
        <p>@item.NewsTitle</p>
      </span>
    </span>       
  </a>                                                                                         
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem then?  What errors are you getting? You should just need to add the updatetargetid to the begin form call to reference the div where you call the Html.Action("GetArticleData"),

Comment: Yes updatetargetid is there but i need to pass the number of times <a> tag is pressed so it can fetch additional records from model. So first time it loads it shows 3 , you press <a> tag it fetches 6 more, you press it again it fetches 6 more and so on

Comment: can't you just update a hidden input?

Comment: I can use hidden input but how would i update them from controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `GetArticleData()` does not take any parameters indicating the `skip` and `take` values, and no where on the client do you store the values. Its not even clear why the model in the partial is `HomePageModel` when all you want is a collection of `News` items. And there is no reason for a form (its a GET method).

The basic approach is

```
public PartialViewResult GetArticleData(int skipCount, int takeCount)
{
  // return a collection of news items based on skip and take, for example
  var model = (from news in db.News orderby news.ID select news).Skip(skipCount).Take(takeCount);
  if (model.Any())
  {
    return PartialView(model);
  }
  else
  {
    return null; // let the client know there is no point calling this again
  }
}
```

Partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<News>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  // Generate html for a news item
}
```

Main View

```
<button id="more">Show more news</button>
<div id="news">
  // Initially display the first 3 items
  @Html.Action("GetArticleData", new { skipCount = 0, takeCount = 3 })
</div>

<script>
  var skip = 3; // start at the 4th record
  var take = 6; // return 6 records at a time
  var hasMoreRecords = true;
  var url = '@Url.Action("GetArticleData")';
  $('#more').click(function() {
    if (!hasMoreRecords) {
      return;
    }
    $.get(url, { skipCount: skip, takeCount: take }, function(response) {
      if (!response) {
        hasMoreRecords = false; // signal no more records to display
      } else {
        $("#news").append(response); // append the returned html
        skip += take; // update for next iteration
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make a json object like this.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
            var ContactID = $("#txtContactId").val();
            var Name = $("#Name").val();
            var Gender = $("#Gender").val();
            var DOB = $("#DOB").val();
            var Photo = $("#Phto").val();
            var PersonTypeID = $("#PersonTypeID").val();
            var Address1 = $("#txtAddress1").val();
            //var Address2 = $("#txtAddress2").val();
            var City = $("#txtCity").val();
            var State = $("#txtState").val();
            var PostalCode = $("#txtPostalCode").val();
            var VatNo = $("#txtVatNo").val();
            var RegNo = $("#txtRegNo").val();
            var Phone = $("#txtPhone").val();
            var Email = $("#txtEmail").val();
            var AdrKey = $("#AdrID").val();


            $.ajax({
                url: "Person/Create",
                data: {
                    //'ContactID': ContactID,
                    'Company': Company,
                    'Status': Status,
                    'IsActive': IsActive,
                    'Comments': Comments,
                    'Country': Country,
                    'Address1': Address1,
                    //'Address2': Address2,
                    'City': City,
                    'State': State,
                    'PostalCode': PostalCode,
                    'VatNo': VatNo,
                    'RegNo': RegNo,
                    'Phone': Phone,
                    'Email': Email
                },
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Successfully Inserted!");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });


        });
```

Post the json function back to controller on submit.
Hope it helps.